# The process ID returned by the CreateProcess function is different from the task manager

Tags: c, windows

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//创建新的控制台
int main(void)
{
    BOOL KillProcess();
    int ret = 0;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = TRUE;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    WCHAR commandline[] = L"notepad.exe";
    //ret = CreateProcess(NULL, commandline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    //WCHAR commandline1[] = L"notepad.exe";
    //WCHAR commandline2[] = L"calc";
    ret = CreateProcess(NULL, commandline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    //ret = CreateProcess(commandline1, commandline2, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    if (ret)
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        printf("threadid = %d\n", pi.dwThreadId);
        printf("processid = %d\n", pi.dwProcessId);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Start successfully\n");
    }
    KillProcess();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

BOOL KillProcess()
{
    DWORD dwProcessId;
    printf("\nPlease input the process ID you want to kill: ");
    scanf_s("%u", &dwProcessId);

    DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_TERMINATE;
    BOOL  bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, dwProcessId);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return FALSE;
    BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    if (result)
    {
        printf("kill process success\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("kill process failed\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

After the code is executed, open the calc.exe pi.dwProcessId ,the process ID returned is different from the PID in the task manager，but open it with code notepad.exe normal.I don't know exactly why. I tried many programs, only the PID of Notepad is the same as task manager
I need help from the big guys. Thank you！

Comment: What happens if you use the `%lu` format specifier in your `printf` calls (as you should for `DWORD` values)?

Comment: Does the process fork?

Comment: Assuming Windows 10, calc.exe is a UWP application. UWP applications consist of at least 2 processes, the sandboxed application and the broker process that negotiates which system services are available to the application. `CreateProcess` doesn't return the information of the actual UWP application, though Task Manager presumably displays it. That's why you observe different results. Notepad, on the other hand, is a classic desktop application.

Comment: The result is the same@Adrian Mole

Comment: It may be so, thank you.@IInspectable

Comment: *calc.exe* is not  UWP application. this is stub which start *calculator.exe* and exit

Comment: So why the process ID returned is different from the PID in the task manager?@RbMm

Comment: Because you are looking at different processes. It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve, though.

Comment: @Congxun - you not view *calc.exe* in task manager